# sup html element doesn't work in Microsoft Edge browser

Tags: html, css

I am displaying the registered trademark symbol on a web page using the sup element as shown below.

```
<sup style="font-size: 15px">®</sup>
```

It works fine in all browsers except in MS Edge. In Edge,  a weird character made of an "A" and an arrowhead is shown along with the intended result. Any idea how to resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: Edge supports sup tag well. There might be wrong something else. How bout used charset? UTF 8?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Can you post the whole document, or a small test document that still exhibits the issue?

Comment: We'll need to know the character set you're serving the page as, and the encoding of the actual text document you're serving, assuming it's simple HTML page... Assuming you're using HTML 5, do you have a `meta` element in your `head` with a charset defined? What is it? (Basically, Edge is probably doing exactly what you're telling it to, but your character encoding is wrong somewhere along the way.)

Comment: Also, what happens if you just serve the ® without wrapping it with the `<sup>`? I'm assuming it'll still be broken, thus eliminating the `<sup>` from our enquiries.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using `&reg;` instead of the symbol itself.

A full list of character references can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_symbols.asp

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!